# EntityFramework 6 out of memory exception

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbset

Hej,

I have a table in database that holds compressed large size file.

when I try to read that file via a `Ef6`. It throws an out of memory exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code is like

```
var payload = repositoryContext.Set<DocumentStore>()  
  .Include(document => document.DocumentStorePayloadData)
  .Single(document => document.Id == 
documentStoreId).DocumentStorePayloadData;``
```

Comment: How big is the file content? Are you running a 32 or 64bit processor? How much available (task manager's value will do) RAM does the machine have?

Comment: The byte size of the content of the file is 571899516. I am running on 64 bit processor. 16gb available ram

Comment: So ~0.5GB. Is this a 32 bit process? What's the processes address allocation? I suspect you're 32bit and in the 2GB address space there isn't a free 0.5GB contiguous block.

Comment: I have 64 bit processor.I saw in the my computer properties. how to find processes address allocation.

Comment: 64 bit processor and OS doesn't mean process is 64bit: many applications (it is the default for many VS projects) are 32bit. [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is easiest way to see a lot of memory details.

Comment: Could you please elaborate little bit. I do not get your point.

Comment: Comments are too short to explain what are basics here. But very briefly: a 64bit CPU can run a 64bit or 32bit version of Windows; a 64bit version of Windows can run 64bit and 32bit processes. A 32bit process has 2GB maximum memory. To create a 0.5GB byte array there must be 0.5GB of contiguous memory available: 25% of the address space in a 32bit process which is quite likely to therefore fail. You need to learn these basics (I recommend a read of *Windows Internals*).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in Visual Studio with debug, I think it only runs as 32 bit.  If you have IIS running in 64-bit on your machine, see if you can run via that instead of via the debugger.  Otherwise, you only have 2 gb total ram which could cause problems trying to load a 500 meg file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a kind of console application that I am running, which trying to fetch large payload from database. Do you know any workaround. I have tried so many options after searching on google, but they didn't help me.

Comment: If it is a console app, you could try to right click on project properties and force it to build under x64.  Then you have to deploy it or run the .exe file directly (no debugging from VS) to see if that worked.

Comment: I tried it. It did not help. Do you have any other idea